# Initialize the members of parent class with an instance of that class from the child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have the following class:

```
public class A
{
    public object Property1 { get; set; }
    public object Property2 { get; set; }
    public object Property3 { get; set; }

    //And for the sake of the example another 20 fields/properties

    public A()
    {

    }
}
```

And another class:

```
public class B : A
{
     //Bunch of other properties...
}
```

I have a method (from different assembly which I cannot change) that returns a new instance of the A class.

Is there a way to cast/convert/initialize class B with all the properties and fields (private fields as well) of class A?

I cannot change anything in class A (it comes from a different assembly)

Is it possible to achieve this without changing the inheritance?

Comment: Why not make B wrap A instead of inherit from it?

Comment: This will probably be my solution. But I would like to know if what I'm asking can be done.

Comment: One possible *trick* to make a copy is serialize/deserialize. In your case `A` can be serialized into something, what is then deserialized as `B`. All `A` properties will be *restored* and all `B` will have default values. The question is how to do it, `XmlSerializer` and `BinarySerializer` will remember type. It is possible to cheat them, but maybe there is better *typeless* serializer (protobuf?). Point is - serializer will do all *dirty* job for you. Obviously, `A` has to be serializable, otherwise you won't get a full copy.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Even if you managed to do it by reflection, it will be against the OOP principle and you have some code that is hard to maintain.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks it does the job. But as it was mentioned I would better wrap A instead of using inheritance. So the code will be more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One think to consider is *composition* over *inheritance*.

```
class B
{
    public A InstanceOfA { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can easily create an instance of B and give it an instance of A.

What you are asking can be done. You can easily copy values of all properties, that's for sure, but as for fields, you would have to use reflection to get their values, because you can't simply cast A to B if A is created as of type A.

Comment: This will probably be my solution. But I would like to know if what I'm asking can be done.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a way to cast/convert/initialize class B

You can try explicit type cast like below example

```
struct Digit
{
byte value;

public Digit(byte value)  //constructor
{
    if (value > 9)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException();
    }
    this.value = value;
}

public static explicit operator Digit(byte b)  // explicit byte to digit conversion operator
{
    Digit d = new Digit(b);  // explicit conversion

    System.Console.WriteLine("Conversion occurred.");
    return d;
}
}

class TestExplicitConversion
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            byte b = 3;
            Digit d = (Digit)b;  // explicit conversion
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Copied code from msdn => [Using Conversion Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a(v=VS.100).aspx)